# Modal window comment editing module (editable text)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frontend

I want to make, that during the ediditing comment action, I have modal window with comment text written inside textarea, and it is editable without deleting all text with clicking. I tried just to put value inside textarea or placing it in placeholder. But both options are wrong and doesnt work. 
Can someone take a look on this code and give me an advice, how should I take for it.

editComment.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Edytuj komentarz</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <label>Treść</label>

                    <textarea class="form-control input-sm"
                              name="description"
                              ng-maxlength="512"
                              ng-model="$ctrl.selected"
                              rows="6">{{comment.value()}}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary"
            type="button"
            ng-disabled="!$ctrl.selected"
            ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">Zapisz
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-raised btn-warning"
            type="button"
            ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Anuluj
    </button>
</div>
```

editComment.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('settlerApplication').controller('EditCommentCtrl', function($uibModalInstance) {

        var $ctrl = this;

        $ctrl.ok = function() {
            $uibModalInstance.close($ctrl.selected);
        };

        $ctrl.cancel = function() {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

    });

})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve. But anyway : if you want to init your textarea's ng-model with $ctrl.foo (comment.value() in your case, from what I understood), you should either :

In the controller, init your $ctrl.selected variable with this value :

```
$ctrl.selected = $ctrl.foo;
```

Or, in your template, use ng-init :

```
<textarea class="form-control input-sm"
          ng-init="$ctrl.selected = $ctrl.foo"
          name="description"
          ng-maxlength="512"
          ng-model="$ctrl.selected"
          rows="6"></textarea>
```

Comment: I have responded below with an explanation. Hope it is written clear enough. Sorry for such a stupid question, but I am learning, and I really dont know how to achieve this. I have another idea, which I am trying to code (without modal window)

Comment: Ok I understood. So as I said, you need to pass the comment value to the controller of your modal, and then init the $ctrl.selected variable with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I am going to explain that a little.

I have modal window like that:
[image: modal window comment]

I want to edit existing comments in this window. And so I want my comment appears instead of text: "Komentarz" (under: "Treść" after clicking in there). And I want that comment text to be editable, so I dont have to write it down again (put the whole text to that area). Is it make it a little better explained about my goal?